# Find the area bounded by these two functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the area bounded by these two functions:
>   $$y = \frac{\ln x}{x}\quad\mbox{and}\quad y = \frac{1}{e} + \frac{(e^2+1)(x-e)}{e^2-1}.$$

Comment: Could you kindly typeset the question?

Comment: And please ask *questions*, don't give orders.

Comment: @Arturo: I think you were also editing when I typeset it. I have undone my edit. Yours look much better,

Comment: @Sivaram: If you don't mind, I'll rollback. Displays are better with the fractions, I want to keep the second function as it was typed, and the quotebox at least makes it seem like the OP is quoting, not ordering the group around.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The area is the integral $\displaystyle \int_{x_1}^{x_2} y dx$ where $y=y_{\text{upper}}-y_{\text{lower}}$.

$y_{\text{upper}} = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ and $y_{\text{lower}} = \frac{1}{e} + \frac{e^2+1}{e^2-1}(x-e)$.

$(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are obtained by equating $y_{\text{lower}}$, $y_{\text{upper}}$

Note: It is easy to obtain $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ by guessing.

Comment: I was wondering how you made the plot? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim: I use the grapher software on os x to make such plots.

Comment: is the software available on Ubuntu? ADDED: okay, just searched it, it is not. Hope there is one.